# do I have control over ads in my own mobile app

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile, blackberry-10

I've search all over Google for this and I couldn't find an answer.

I will be building my first mobile app and I was wondering how much control do I have regarding advertising banners. That last thing I want my users to see, is some annoying banner at the bottom of my application.

As a new mobile app developer, how much control do I really have over adverting, especially from third parties in my own application?...

Comment: You will have to create a layout that embeds the banner view at the exact location where you want it to go. Nobody is going to force a random location on you. Make sure to read Google's guidelines for ads in Android apps: http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html

Answer (score 0):

Ads are not an automatic thing in Android apps-- you have to choose to put them in there. For example, view [this](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/admob-tutorial-add-ads-to-your-application.7300/) link where people ask *how* to add advertisements.

It should be mentioned that ads can be a good thing for a free app, and being that it's under your control, it's up to you to put the ads in a way that do not disrupt the user experience (like banner ads often do).

Answer (score 0):

Third party ads are most of the time not in your control since custom ads violates their advertiser interest.

Some third party network provide custom ad showing option but in that cases you generate very little to none amount of money for the clicks.

You can become a advertiser in some ad networks and then can push your own ads.. really costly . probably a not good solution.

Position wise - most of the ad networks have banner + fullscreen ads and custom placement is available.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ad services, I use and would recommend admob which is Google's own.

You have a lot of control over the ads, where they are displayed, this is done by adding the ad element to the layout xml file so you can place where you think is appropriate in your apps layout.

When to request an, auto refresh the ad after so many seconds/minutes. Also from the web interface you can control what category adverts are shown from, for example, if you didn't want to show dating adverts within your app from the web site you can block the dating category so none of your users will see adverts for that category.

You can find out more info about admob at http://www.admob.com.